# Shortest path preventing particular edge combinations

Tags: networkx, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have been using networkX to compute the shortest path distance between two points A and B in a graph thanks to Dijkstra's algorithm.
The edges of my graph represent road segments, and the nodes the connections between segments. The weight function is the segment length, so that the returned path distance is the actual geographical distance.

However, the calculated paths are sometimes unrealistic for my use. More specifically, I would like to prevent the algorithm from using paths implying very sharp turns between two successive edges. This implies that the weight of a particular edge is a function of the edge itself, but also of its precedessor in the path (so that the turn angle can be computed and sharp turns dismissed).

As a (simplistic) example, let's consider the below graph (assuming that the nodes and represented according to their actual geographical position). For the sake of simplicity, each edge has a weight (or distance) equal to 1.
The shortest path from A to B is shown in green, and the corresponding distance is 2.

Shortest path without "sharp turn" constraint
[image]

However, the proposed path involve a sharp turn at node C (which can be detected based on the geographical coordinates of nodes A, B and C). This kind of turn should be forbidden, such that the proposed shortest path becomes the one described below.

Shortest path with "sharp turn" constraint
[image]

The distance is now 6, but the path avoids the transition A-B-C which involved a sharp turn.

What do you think are my options to implement such requirement?

Comment: I'm guessing each node has a coordinate. Can you share a minimal example, and an expected output? Also please clarify what can be considered as a "sharp turn"

Comment: Question has been edited with an example. The definition of "sharp turn" would be based on the heading difference between 2 successive edges above a defined threshold. However, on a more generic perspective, the question is rather about the definition of _edge weight_ based on its _predecessor in the path_.

Comment: You could implement a method to calculate the cost on the fly based on the two  connected nodes (say B and C) and the previous node (A). If going from A to B and C involves a sharp turn, make the cost infinite.

Comment: Indeed, I can _technically_ implement a weight function that would calculate the weight from B to C considering the predecessor of B. However, I have the feeling that doing so would prevent the algorithm from working as expected. As an example, if B has several potential predecessors (let's say A1 and A2), and the shortest path to B is obtained by passing through A1, the algorithm will store A1 as the predecessor of B. Now, if the next edge is C and (A1-B-C) is not possible as it involves a sharp turn, the algorithm will never try to consider A2 as a possible predecessor of B.

Comment: Tip: adding @username (i.e @c0der) to a message alerts the user of that message. I think you need to store only the fixed weight of B-C and add to it, on the fly (calculate) additional cost that is angle dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar by making it a multi edge graph. Such as there is more than one edge between any two nodes. The 2nd edge in your case could be a numerical value identifying the orientation of the edge(road).

Considering south to north as 0, you could assign -180 to 180 to each orientation and then your algorithm need only compute the difference between the two weights of these edges to figure out if the node is sharp turn and thus eliminate it.

Look up “multgraph” or “multidigraph” in networkx api for implementation

One edge has to be distance other has to be orientation, encoding both orientation and distance to a single weight will require trignometric coding from a central (0) point

Comment: I am not sure exactly about how a multi edge graph would help. The problem I am facing is not the calculation of edge orientation, but how to consider the orientation of the _previous_ edge in the shortest path algorithm. In Dijkstra's algorithm, the edge weight betwen nodes a and b is a function of a and b only. I am not sure that implementing a dependency on the _predecessor_ of a would still allow the algorithm to work as expected.

Comment: @G. Vaurs, What did you eventually end up implementing?